# dynamic site link for future migration in echo do_shortcode()

Tags: functions, multisite, shortcode, site-url

I'm doing like an WP archive migration of old sites/themes which seems to only work under php 5.5 and WP 3.8.22

There are some site URL which are absolute as for a json timeline.

How could I have a dynamic link such as `bloginfo('url')`, `site_url`, `home_url` ,`base_url()` etc (which will be dynamically changed when migrating) inserted in place of `MYSITEURL` here ?

```
echo do_shortcode("[timeline src='MYSITEURL/blog/api/timeline/category_posts/?category_id=4&hash_bookmark=true&start_zoom_adjust=3&main_post_id=1136']");
```

Comment: Why you're not trying to search-replace database method after migration ?  here is one useful plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/

Answer (score 1):

You can save your website's URL into a variable and pass it to the shortcode:

```
$url = site_url();

echo do_shortcode("[timeline src='$url/rest-of-the-url/']");
```

You should also be able to use your shortcode in the following way:

```
echo do_shortcode("[timeline src='".site_url()."/rest-of-the-url/']");
```